# How can I remove css class inside a div in the result of an ajax response

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

My ajax response is working and showing the content of the result but I always have the CSS effects but I don't want it.

I want to remove the `class="container body-content"` on the following `div` in the result that I receive from the ajax call.

```
<div id="bodyRendered" class="container body-content">

</div>
```

---

I have tried to remove in the result and after the affectation to my content `div` id named `RepechageRestant`:

```
$('body').on('click', '#RepechageRestant .pagination a', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var url = $(this).attr('href');

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function(result) {
                    var $myresult = $(result);
                    $myresult.find('#footer').remove();

                    $('#RepechageRestant').html($myresult);

                    $("#bodyRendered").removeClass("body-content");
                    $("#bodyRendered").removeClass("container");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

-- the result is put inside this `div`:

```
<div id="RepechageFait" style="padding-top: 30px">

</div>
```

Comment: you can remove the class from the server before the response..

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling you have a typo. Try the following:

```
 console.log($("#bodyRendered").attr("class"));
 $("#bodyRendered").removeClass("container body-content");
 console.log($("#bodyRendered").attr("class"));
```

What happens? Note that you can remove multiple classes in with `removeClass`.

Comment: Could you point to the typo please? I tried to find it in the code but couldn't.

Comment: I didn't see the typo either I have just replace my code with your code and it works. Tanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it doesn't work because the `html()` and `removeClass()` functions are in the same scope (`$.ajax()`) and execute simultaneously, i.e, the classes are tried to be removed even before the html content has loaded. You can try to use either callback (*although html function doesn't allow callback*) or `promise()` to ensure that the `html()` function has finished loading content before trying to remove class.

```
$('#RepechageRestant').html($myresult).promise().done(function(){
    $("#bodyRendered").removeClass("container body-content");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

thedeeno is correct, there is a typo.

```
 console.log($("#bodyRendered").attr("class"));
 $("#bodyRendered").removeClass("container body-content");
 console.log($("#bodyRendered").attr("class"));
```